# Smooth approximation to the floor function for use with backpropagation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, math

I have been trying to implement a smooth approximation to the `np.floor` function. I need a smooth implementation as `np.floor` cannot be backpropagated through in my program.

I came up with a solution that involves the sum of many logistic functions, however the performance is horrible when the numbers are large.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit

def multiexpit(x, slope=50):
    y = np.asarray([ expit(slope*(x-i)) for i in range(int(np.max(x))) ])
    return np.sum(y,axis=0)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
    plt.plot(x,np.floor(x),label='floor')
    plt.plot(x,multiexpit(x-1),label='smooth floor')
```

The results are quit good however. Here the approximation is shown against the floor function, with a temperature parameter `slope=50`:

[image]

My question is if it is possible to implement this function with a runtime that does not depend on the value of the inputs? Does tensorflow have something similar? I am using numpy but the problem is the same with TF.

Comment: Can you give me a sample input for large numbers. I have prepared a solution but would like to compare its performance. So it would be helpful if you tell me some execution time for a large sample input and give me that input so that I can tell what I get

Comment: You may have already found this on Google but anyway, related from Mathematics.SE: [Smooth floor function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2746958)

Comment: I think the link by @jdehesa might be a good idea. I highly doubt that the "smooth" version in your image will provide useful gradients for backpropagation -- they are almost always either near-0 (meaning learning will be extremely slow/impossible) or extremely large (probably leading to instability). Although I guess that might simply be a matter of setting the "temperature" parameter differently.

Comment: Gradients are not explicitly dependent on the outcomes of the floor function, as they are discrete samples of a random matrix of which I need to compute eigenvalues. Experiments with Bernoulli like reparameterization gave me extremely precise results, I wanted to sample geometric random variables with this specific reparameterization and the flooor function stops the gradients.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the repeated `expit`, I guess there is no way to get around the sum, so the only thing you can do is to let `numpy` take care of the `for` loop. One way to do that would be to convert both your x-values and the positions of the steps into 2d arrays using `meshgrid`:

```
def multiexpit2(x, slope=50):
    i = np.arange(int(min(x)//1),int(max(x)//1)+1)
    X, I = np.meshgrid(x,i)
    return np.sum(expit(slope*(X-I)),axis=0)+min(x)//1-1
```

The addition of `min(x)//1-1` corrects for any situations where your x-values don't start from zero.